# How do I create an in memory DbContext with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How do I create an in memory version of a DbContext for testing in entity framework 6? I cannot use .NET core for this project, it must be e.f. 6. I already have a custom db context created that connects to sql server and works great.

Doing this in .NET core is trivial, I am hoping something exists for legacy entity framework / .NET framework as well, but so far no luck on my searches...